# Java code, arithmetic and if/else statement issue

Tags: java, math

Hoping someone can give me a hand with this code. The beginning of the code you will see my psudo which states what I'm attempting to do. Only ever written in C++ before so the conversion is throwing me off some.

```
package correctFare;


/* create static variables for figures that will remain constant throughout program (fare,dollar value etc.)
 * 
 * create variable that will be used to store the amount of money the user states is entered (entered amount must be 0=<x<=20
 * Prompt user to enter the amount of money they are inserting which will be stored in the input var.
 *      note* remind user that amount must be divisable by .25 and no greater than 20.0
 * 
 * subtract 2.25 from input, if the input-fare is not >= zero report error insufficient funds
 * divide input by 0.25, if the number is not a whole number, int, report error and state that all values bust be multiples of 25 cents
 * 
 * create open double variable as 'change'
 * take input, subtract 2.25 and store new amount as change
 * 
 * change is then divided by static variable ten, if zero continue to next step, else store amount as tenChange, change-(tenChange*10) continue to next step
 * follow with dividing change by 5, same steps as prior
 * repeat again with one
 * lastly finish with quarters
 * 
 * Prompt user with total cost of fare, amount entered and then tendered cash broken into each denomination
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CTAFare {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

            static double fare=2.25;            //fare amount, remains easily accessible
            static double quarter=0.25;         //denomination amounts stored as static variables
            static int oneDollar=1;
            static int fiveDollar=5;
            static int tenDollar=10;
            static int twentyDollar=20;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

        int max = 20;
        int min = 0;
        double inputAmount;

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you wish to insert:");
        System.out.println("\n *Please note, this machine will accept bills no larger than $20 and must be divisible by $0.25.");
            inputAmount = in.nextDouble();

            if (min <= inputAmount <= max) 
        {
            System.out.println("You entered: $"+ inputAmount);
        }
        else if (max < inputAmount < min)
        {
            System.out.println("The amount you entered is not acceptable.");
        }

            double change;
            int tenChange;
            int fiveChange;
            int oneChange;
            int quarterChange;

        inputAmount-fare = change;

        if (change/tenDollar > 0) {
            change/tenDollar = tenChange;
            change - (tenChange*10) = change;

        }
        else if (change/fiveDollar > 0) {
            change/five = fiveChange;
            change - (fiveChange * 5) = change;

        }
        else if (change/oneDollar > 0) {
            change/onDollar = oneChange;
            change - (oneChange * 1) = change;
        }
        else if (change/quarter > 0) {
            change/quarter = quarterChange;
            change - (quarter*0.25) = change;
        }

        System.out.println("You have purchased one fare at $"+ fare".\n");
        System.out.println("Amount insterted: $"+ inputAmount "\n");
        System.out.println("Change tendered: \n");
        System.out.println("Ten Dollar Bills: "+ tenChange " \n");
        System.out.println("Five Dollar Bills: "+ fiveChange " \n");
        System.out.println("One Dollar Bills: "+ oneChange " \n");
        System.out.println("Quarters: "+ quarterChange " \n");



    }

}
```

Comment: Could you be more brief and specific in your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments in C++ are done from right to left, and I'm assuming that's similar for Java. Try changing your assignments...

```
change/five = fiveChange;
```

should be

```
fiveChange = change/five;
```

In this example, too, you haven't defined what five is anywhere. Unlike in Python, you need to define your variables before or when you use them.

Also, you might want to consider what each type is. I'm not sure int is the best choice in some of your circumstances. Try fixing your assignments and declarations, then see if your output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem I noticed

```
if (min <= inputAmount <= max)
```

try using

```
if (min <= inputAmount && inputAmount <= max)
```

Here is another mistake

```
 change/five = fiveChange;
```

You cant do this. Try following

```
 double newFiveCHange =  change/five ;
```

or interchang them like

```
 fiveChange = change/five;
```

Following are useful links you can use.

[1. Summary of Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

[2. The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

[3. Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Comment: your condition is wrong too : `if (min >= inputAmount && inputAmount  <= max)` none reachable condition.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly I am not sure what condition he wanted. I am just giving him heads up how to correct them. Moreover he has lots of mistake in his code.

Comment: if (min <= inputAmount <= max) -> if (min <= inputAmount && inputAmount  <= max) i guess

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thanks for update, I dont wanted to make that change as It OPs work how to sort them out. I just wanted to show how they can be used in code. However I made the update.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace :

`if (min <= inputAmount <= max)`

by

`if (min <= inputAmount && inputAmount <= max)`

and replace :

`else if (max < inputAmount < min)`

by

`else`

Comment: Could you add the error code or the exception details ?